# Javafx: CustomMenuItem width

Tags: javafx, menuitem

I use the code from Ballage1551 from this post:
[Adapt TableView menu button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27739833/adapt-tableview-menu-button)

The problem: 
The CustomMenuItem ist filled with a Label-Node. But actions only work on clicking directly on the Label. It it is a short Label, there is a lot of area to the right without any use.

Any Idea how to make CutomMenuItem funtion as a MenuItem -> clicking anywhere in the MenuItems fires the event.

Thank you

Comment: yes, create a group with a rectangle or pane as its backdrop then put the label on top of the group, set the action to the group instead thus it will see the pane/rectangle as part of the button and use its area as the button as well.

Comment: Can't figure out how to implement what you wrote. Group/Pane don't have an setOnAction. Can you explain with an example Code maybe?

Comment: yes, you can use the `group.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) { /* what you want it to do here */ }});` and to change on mouse out `group.setOnMouseExited` and `group.setOnMouseReleased` to make it do an action on release. The same works for Panes.

Comment: It is not possible to add a Group to an ContextMenu. My code:`final ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();

        final Group group = new Group(new Rectangle());
        final Label test = new Label("Test");
        group.getChildren().add(test);
        
        cm.getItems().add(group);`