# Javafx : Remove an item from TableMenu

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8, popupmenu

I have a `TableView` with `setTableMenuButtonVisible(true)` but i want to remove the "x-th" item from the contextMenu list so the user cannot hide that column. I found the `columnPopupMenu` in the `TableHeaderRow` but I don't know how to manage it's items. Is there a possibility without a dirty workaround?

Comment: Can you post some code??

Comment: I have solved the problem with a custom menu, this posts accepted answer helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27739833/adapt-tableview-menu-button. I thought it could be solved much easier but I didn't find any simple solution.